# How to display a text field on the same page by clicking on a link

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to display a text field on clicking a link on the same page.

html file

```
<a href="" onclick="disp_qa()">Add another question</a><br/><br />
<script>
    function disp_qa()
    {
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("form_da").style.display = "block";
    }

</script>
```

These does not seems to work.
How can i do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you should reed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0/134957#134957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost there:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="disp_qa()">Add another question</a><br/><br />
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGYhE/

another way:

```
<a href="" onclick="disp_qa(event)">Add another question</a><br/><br />
```

**JS**:

```
function disp_qa(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("form_da").style.display = "block";
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGYhE/4/